# How do I use a leading slash with the url() function?

Tags: templating

[The `url()` function](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions#url) won't work with a leading slash as it's path parameter.

For example, this: `{{ url('jobs') }}`
Outputs: `http://example.com/jobs`

But this: `{{ url('/jobs') }}`
Just outputs: `/jobs`

This is easy enough to remember for developers, but if you're passing a variable from a user input field like `{{ url(entry.myField) }}`, users can accidentally break a link if they add a leading slash.

How can I make the `url()` function more resilient when relying on an unknown variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `trim` filter to automatically remove leading and trailing slashes like so:

```
{{ url( entry.myField | trim('/') )  }}
```